# How to print from a Canon MG2120

Tags: printing, canon

I am not able to print from my Ubuntu machine to my Canon MG2120 printer. Canon does not have a driver for this printer on a Linux machine.  I do not know if a driver is required.
Can it be done on my current operating system?  Can it be done on the new one that is being offered for download.

Comment: What's your _current operating system_ ?

Comment: Current operating system -- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Download and install these drivers : [MG2100 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.60 for Linux](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100392602.html).

You'll have to untar it with `tar -xvzf cnijfilter-mg2100series-3.60-1-deb.tar.gz`, then install the deb file : `sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-mg2100series-3.60-1-deb`.

Should be fine.

Comment: I'll give it a try later this week.  Thank You for your suggestion.  I'll let you know how it works

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  The printer now works.  I should make the following comments.  When you unpack the tar file, you get a directory containing several files.  One of these files is a script.  You need to run the script to get it to work.

Comment: If this worked, can you validate my answer ? And I will update it to mention the script.

Comment: I hope that I successfully validated your answer.  This is the first time that I have used this website.  If not, please tell how to do it.